# Angular 2 same component multiple times is executing 1 by 1

Tags: angular, components

Created a component named running-number.componet.ts,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'running-number',
  templateUrl: './running-number.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./running-number.component.css']
})
export class RunningNumberComponent implements OnInit {

  private currentValue:number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  @Input() numberForRunning:number;

  ngOnInit() {
      let obj = this;
      for (let i = 1; i <= obj.numberForRunning; i++ ) {
          setTimeout(() => {
              this.currentValue = this.currentValue + 1;
          }, 100);
      }
  }

}
```

and called this component 4 times with different numberForRunning input values.

```
<running-number numberForRunning="15645"></running-number>
<running-number numberForRunning="3543"></running-number>
<running-number numberForRunning="414"></running-number>
<running-number numberForRunning="987"></running-number>
```

Issues is once numberForRunning="15645" is completely done. then only numberForRunning="3543" is started. i want all the 4 components should run simultaneously. Please help me for fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am seeing non-deterministic behavior which is expected. That is not a reliable way to interleave operations.

Comment: what is this running component supposed to do exactly? I think you're trying  to implement a component that has a counter that ticks every 100 ms up to a target number. But your implementation is definitely NOT going to do that... you're creating a bunch of timeouts that are all set to fire at the same time (200 ms from now).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? post your template code too.

Comment: Take a look at this https://plnkr.co/edit/wtV73Nd3qc4NecryKwSg (note heavily edited for style) here we have slowed down the rate of change (with the assistance of `async/await`) and made it parametric so that we can observe it is indeed possible. The issue has to do with the queuing of iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that, as each component is initialized, its initializer is run synchronously until it finishes. While we are indeed queuing up changes that can be interleaved by calling `setTimeout`, and I believe interleaving is what you are after behavior-wise, it is actually happening synchronously. Each component instance is actually synchronously creating `numberForRunning` timeouts, immediately before any other component's initializer is executed. This actually chokes up the event loop making the results difficult to observe.

We actually can achieve the interleaved updates by leveraging Promises. In the following example we leverage Promises, along with `async`/`await` in order to make each iteration within the init loop of some component depend on (literally `await`) the previous iteration.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'running-number',
  template: '<div>{{currentValue}}</div>'
})
export class RunningNumberComponent implements OnInit {

  private currentValue = 0;

  @Input() numberForRunning: number;

  @Input() rateOfChange = 1;

  async ngOnInit() {
    const period = 1000 * this.rateOfChange;
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.numberForRunning; i++) {
      await delay(period);
      this.currentValue = this.currentValue + 1;
    }
  }

}

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(undefined), ms));
}
```

Here it is, running, https://plnkr.co/edit/9bnwr4wNQPbIergDTq1n?p=preview

This works because it means that the initializers actually return Promises which in turn beget more Promises. Instead of performing their work *synchronously* it is interleaved. So initialization and the subsequent operations that happen over time as a result of the process thusly started actually gets interleaved. The `rateOfChange` property is introduced to allow us to see this happening more easily.

I apologize as this is somewhat hand-waving but I hope it gets at the underlying issues and provides a high level illustration.

Comment: Thanks for this. Working fine.